# How to invoke call event in my Iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, call, contacts

here is the scenario:
I have fetched the iphone contact details into my application.And i have displayed email,phone details my View controller.
Now,I want to know how to invoke call event which i click on phone number in my application?

Comment: The only way is using a `tel:` event, like rckoenes describes below.

Comment: The call event fires only in device .It does not fire in simulator right?

Comment: i think an alert asking if you want to call this number is shown on the simulator too. but nothing else will happen.

Comment: How to show the alert.Can you please tell me or give a code snippet ?

Comment: Err what? Have you actually looked in the Apple Developer Documentation?  This alert is generated by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"tel://1234567890"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Comment: the // are not needed, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

Well you just call the `tel` scheme:

```
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234564897"];

BOOL hasPhone = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL];

if (hasPhone) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

[Apple URL scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: The call event fires only in device  .It does not fire in simulator right?

Comment: Correct, you could always check if the device supports the url with the `canHandleURL` methods

Comment: Sorry the methods is called `canOpenURL`, not `canHandleURL`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];
```